keyboard input sometimes loses or drops characters when typing in Windows VM running on Mac
keyboard input sometimes loses or drops characters when typing in Windows VM running on Mac? I'm running Win11 using UTM on MacOS Sequoia 15.2.
I was typing in commands in PowerShell and occasionally I can't type certain letters? I was trying to type "clear" at the PowerShell prompt - and it would come out as "lear".  I could Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V and that worked.  I found I could type Shift-C and type "Clear" which worked and then all of a sudden I could use the "c" key again.
Bizzare.  Anyone else seen this and know of the cause / fix?
UPDATE: using UTM v4.6.3 running their QEMU 7.2 ARM virtual machine image (virt-7.2) with utm-guest-tools-latest.iso installed. Win11 image using CrystalFetch.
Running ver in CMD reports: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.26100.2605]
Keyboard works fine in macos. no special keyboard mappings.
It only happens infrequently but so far it's happened 2x in Powershell 7.4.6

Presumably your keyboard works ok when not in the VM? Are the VM and macOS using the same / equivalent keyboard mapping?

In addition to the previous questions, does this occur only in PowerShell or in other Windows applications?

Are you running an ARM VM or an x86 emulation?

updated main post with answers to specific questions.. UPDATE: using UTM v4.6.3 running their QEMU 7.2 ARM virtual machine image (virt-7.2) with utm-guest-tools-latest.iso installed. Win11 image using CrystalFetch. Running ver in CMD reports: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.26100.2605]
Keyboard works fine in macos. no special keyboard mappings.
It only happens infrequently but so far it's happened 2x in Powershell 7.4.6
